# Kol Isha specifically from/of a woman?

Tags: halacha-theory, technology, kol-isha

I have been reviewing the questions related to Kol Isha (including links about parrots, men with feminine voices, radio recordings and Siri singing) but I was asked whether halacha has dealt with voice [transposers](https://www.google.com/search?q=voice%20transposer&rlz=1C1SQJL_enUS855US855&oq=voice%20transposer&aqs=chrome..69i57.3040j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

One can buy a technology that can, in real time, modulate a person's voice so that it sounds different (and shifting the pitch can make it sound male or female).

IS the underlying prohibition related to the sound of a woman's voice and the thoughts it can inspire (ignoring the subtlety in opinions related to whether the listener has seen an image of the singer) based in the sound of the voice, or the source of the voice?

Can a woman with a bad singing voice, or a voice shifted to sound male inspire thoughts simply because she, as a source, is still a woman? Or must the voice "sound like" a woman to do its part in triggering the thoughts?

Comment: Why is this "transposer" different from all the questions you "reviewed"? We can find 1000 other versions of "not actually a woman" and we don't need to ask all of them.

Comment: Then I promise I won't ask "all of them." But this isn't the case of a parrot or a recording, or a radio. It is about the underlying theory of the voice as connected to a gender, or the voice's standing on its own. If you feel that this duplicates one of the various questions, feel to mark it as a duplicate and point me to a question which addresses my area of inquiry precisely so I can leave with an understanding. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems exactly the same as a radio and a parrot to me. Not a woman but sounds like a woman ish. Same thing.

Comment: The radio case brings in the distance and issue of recording whereas the parrot isn't actually a human. The filter question seems perfectly on point so I appreciate that catch!

Comment: I don't know what distance, recording or humanity have to do with anything.